# Grails async programming ,how to pass value return from promise in then block?

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I am using grails async programming .  I need to pass result return from promise into then block and do process on this . but I am not sure how to do .

Sample case :

```
Promise promise = task {
    // long running task
    return promiseResult
}
promise.then {
    // want to process promiseResult here
}
```

In above , I want to perform some process on the "promiseResult" return from promise in "then" block .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Promise promise = task {
     return promiseResult
}
promise.then { prevPromiseResult ->
    // Access prevPromiseResult which is the result of the previous promise
}
```

`Promise.then` takes a closure as a parameter which is similar to `onComplete(Closure callable)`. Passing previous promise's result as a parameter to the closure should give access to the result.

Same should be applicable for `onError()`.